# python openpyxl get sheet names

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror, openpyxl

I am starting on a code that loads and edits excel (the version I am using is office 2017) sheet using openpyxl. Right now I am still trying to wrap my head around how this module works, here's the code

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import workbook
from openpyxl.compat import range
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
import os
os.chdir("D:\Scripts\Python\Testing Scripts\My Excel Folder")

wb = load_workbook("MyExcel.xlsx")
names = wb.sheetnames()

print(names)
print(type(wb))
```

and the error I receive is,

> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

For the string of code

`names = wb.sheetnames()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

wb.get_sheet_names() returns the list of all the sheets in that excel workbook.

```
print (wb.get_sheet_names())
```

for the latest openpyxl to avoid warning:

```
print (wb.sheetnames)
```

if you want to access a particular sheet

```
 ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name(name = 'Sheet 1')
```

Comment: this solution works, but it gives this warning |||  DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function get_sheet_names (Use wb.sheetnames)

Comment: Added the changes for the warning.

Comment: It still gives the warning

Comment: Yea man I am totally stoned, corrected the code finally. Accept if it works without any warning @Nickiel

Comment: Why does the depreciated code use parenthesis but the new .sheetnames don't? thanks anyway

Comment: It also works in your first example as wb.sheetnames if there are no parenthesis and by itself such as `names = wb.sheetnames`

Answer (score 1):

**Use: wb.sheetnames**

Example -

```
names = wb.sheetnames
print(names)
```

Do not use: get_sheet_names()
If you will use this, you will get this Warning.
**DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function get_sheet_names (Use wb.sheetnames).**